# DATEDIFF FUNCTION in MySQL got a weird miss match in the results

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and I am practice on Leetcode with the questions. When I try to solve Leetcode question 550 Game Analysis IV, I have got stuck with the test case 6. It seems I always missed some players with my code. But I double checked many times and did not got what is wrong there. So I came here try to ask some experts. Thanks so much for help me out!

**The question:**

| Column Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| player_id | int |
| device_id | int |
| event_date | date |
| games_played | int |

(player_id, event_date) is the primary key of this table. This table shows the activity of players of some games. Each row is a record of a player who logged in and played a number of games (possibly 0) before logging out on someday using some device.

> Write an SQL query to report the fraction of players that logged in again on the day after the day they first logged in, rounded to 2 decimal places. In other words, you need to count the number of players that logged in for at least two consecutive days starting from their first login date, then divide that number by the total number of players.

**My answer to the question:**

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT a1.player_id, a1.event_date logindate, a2.event_date followdate
  FROM Activity a1 LEFT JOIN Activity a2 on 
   (a1.player_id = a2.player_id AND datediff(a2.event_date,a1.event_date)=1)
)

SELECT ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN followdate is not null then 1 else 0 end)/count(t2.firstdate)
           ,2)fraction
FROM
    (SELECT  player_id,MIN(logindate) firstdate, followdate
     FROM t1
     GROUP BY player_id
   ) t2
```

**My wrong answer:**

The right answer for case 6 is 0.12, and I got 0.11 instead. I can pass some test cases, but I cannot pass case 6.

**My debug:**

I tried the following code to check whether I got the wrong table with `WITH`statement.

```
SELECT a1.player_id, a1.event_date logindate, a2.event_date followdate
FROM Activity a1 
LEFT JOIN Activity a2 on (a1.player_id = a2.player_id
    AND datediff(a2.event_date,a1.event_date)=1)
```

And it seems I will have a mismatch for player 89:

| player_id | MIN(logindate) | followdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 89 | 2019-01-18 | 2019-02-27 |

the wrong `followdate`(diff between `MIN(logindate)` and `followdate` should be 1.

I also tried to change the datetime function during the debug, such as `a2.event_date = DATE_ADD(a1.logindate,interval 1 day)` , BUT the mismatch continues.

**Could someone help me with:**

Check if I use the wrong datetime function OR there is something wrong in my code.

***Thanks a lot for the discussions and helps!***

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT a1.player_id, a1.event_date logindate, a2.event_date followdate
  FROM Activity a1 LEFT JOIN Activity a2 on 
   (a1.player_id = a2.player_id AND datediff(a2.event_date,a1.event_date)=1)
)

SELECT ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(followdate,firstdate)=1 then 1 else 0 end)/count(*)
           ,2)fraction
FROM
    (SELECT  player_id,MIN(logindate) firstdate, min(followdate) followdate
     FROM t1
     GROUP BY player_id
   ) t2
```

Comment: It can pass first 5 test cases, but still got stuck at test case 6, and got a result: fraction =0.71 , which should be 0.12

Comment: I'll update answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will also look into the test case row by row to find out the reason.